# image used as image map highlights onclick

Tags: css, mobile-safari, mobile-webkit

I am having an image that is being used as an image map.Image map highlights as gray onclick.I want no highlightening.This doesnot happens on safari on mac.However, this happens only on ipad simulator/device.

Comment: Is there any CSS on it? When you hover the image? Check it out with Firebug

Comment: Can you show the detail coding?

Comment: no i am not using css.I am seeing this html in ipad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use CSS on your images

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

it will set the highlight color to fully transparent (alpha 0) black making it not display if you will set alpha to 1.0 on the other hand you will make the highlight to fully cover the clickable area.

refer to [Safari CSS Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html) for more details